# Simulation Dickey-Fuller distribution

Tags: statistics, time-series

I tried to simulate the Dickey- Fuller statistics with a short Matlab routine. 
I set Y0=0 and generated
$$
Y_{t}=Y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t,
$$
where $\epsilon_t$ is  $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$-distributed. Then I estimate the model
$$
\Delta Y_t = \beta Y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t
$$
and computed the Dickey-Fuller statistic in order to estimate the quantile.

---

```
 function [Y] = genY(n)
 %generate random walk.
 Y=zeros(1,n);
 Y(1)=0;
 for i=2:n
     Y(i)=Y(i-1)+randn;
 end
 end
```

---

```
 function [dist] = estBeta(n)
 %estimate  Dickey-Fuller statistics in one step
 Y=genY(n);
 DeltaY=Y(2:n)-Y(1:(n-1));
 est=(sum(DeltaY(2:end).*DeltaY(1:(end-1))))/(sum((DeltaY(1:(end-1))).^2));
 dist=est/(std(DeltaY)/sqrt(n-1));
 end
```

---

```
 function [quantil] = perc(m)
 %calculation of quantile
 z=zeros(1,m);
 for i=1:m
    z(i)=estBeta(1000);
 end
 quantil=quantile(z,0.01);
 end
```

If I execute the program I will always end up with -2.3 at p=0.01.
Has anybody an idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Put four spaces in front of each line of code to improve the readability.

Comment: "Dickey- Fuller statistics" are not universally known. Could you give a thorough reference ?

Comment: Thanks! You are right, it should be renamed to "Dickey-Fuller distribution". In fact, I want to reproduce the critical values given by Dickey-Fuller table (regarding no trend and no constant): http://www.real-statistics.com/statistics-tables/augmented-dickey-fuller-table/ . The paper I use can be found in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0185084914704372

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution for the no contant no trend case (you can adapt the code for further model specifications).

1. Set up the number of replications, I have done this in a for loop so that you can change it to meet your requirements.
2. Deriving the DF tests state see W.

   ```
   %% Replicating Dickey and Fuller critical values
   ```

   for q = [25,50,100,250,500]
       T = q; 
       reps = 5000000;
       DFstats = zeros(1,reps);

   ```
   for i = 1:reps
       u = normrnd(0,1,[1,T]);
       W = 1/sqrt(T)*cumsum(u);
       DFstats(i)=W(T)^2-1/(2*sqrt(mean(W.^2)));
   end 

   CV = sort(DFstats);
   ActualValues = CV([(0.01*reps),(0.05*reps),(0.1*reps)]);
   ActualTable(:,q)=ActualValues;
   ```

   end